# Как выводить 3 числа 1, 1000, 1000000 по кругу в цикле?

Tags: c++

Подскажите как получить такой результат в цикле, числа не сложные и думаю что можно как то это сделать через умножение.

```
1
1000
1000000
1
1000
1000000
1
1000
1000000
...
```

я знаю есть такой механизм реализации но у меня не получается сделать это для своего варианта.

```
int i = 0;
for (;;) { // я бы не хотел трогать цикл
    i = (i + 1) % 4;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

}
```

выдает такой результат:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
....
```

Еще я смог сделать то что мне нужно но нагородил мне кажется много лишнего, я бы не хотел использовать массив.

```
int ar[]{1,1000,1000000};
int i = 0;
for (;;i = (i + 1) % 3) {
    
    std::cout << ar[i] << std::endl;

}
```

результат выдает то что нужно:

```
1
1000
1000000
1
1000
1000000
...
```

и т.д

это для меня не подходит, мне нужно каждый раз выдавать по 1 числу а не сразу 3

```
cout << 1 << endl << 1000 << endl << 1000000 << endl;
```

Comment: Можно за одну итерцию сразу выводить три числа.

Comment: @EOF это не подходит для меня

Comment: попробуйте умножать 1 на 1000 в степени i.

Comment: @Эникейщик пробовал но там по кругу когда идет он дает 0 и умножение не работает. Если я правильно вас понимаю.

Comment: Да почему же не работает. 1000 в степени 0 равно 1, 1*1 равно 1. Все как надо.

Comment: @Эникейщик можете показать на ответе?

Comment: @EOF а можно как то не трогать цикл for?

Comment: А какой цикл тогда трогать?

Comment: @EOF я хочу что бы цикл был таким `for(;;)` в любом случае вы используете if условие и static_cast а так же pow я думаю это все будет замедлять скорость программы

Comment: Сделайте массив A={1,1000,1000000} и выводите A[i%3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия с операторами `if - else`. [Пример](https://ideone.com/gaVXRc):

```
for(;;){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    if(i < 1000000) i *= 1000;
    else i = 1;
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
for(;;){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i = (i * 1000) % 1000000000;
        if(i == 0) ++i;
}
```

Третий (худший в плане читабельности) вариант:

```
#include <cmath>
...
for(;;){
        std::cout << exp(((i++) % 3) * log(1000)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: это будет работать медленно

Comment: если вы сможете избавится от проверки if будет супер. я такой вариант уже делал но так и не придумал как избавиться от `0`

Comment: @tomi if будет работать медленно? Зачем эта непомерная оптимизация? Да просто вывод cout будет в тыщу раз медленнее этой проверки.

Comment: @MBo само собой я `cout` удалю будет только то что нужно

Comment: в 3 версии появилось `exp` и `log` :)

Comment: Любое "то, что нужно", т.е. полезная работа, будет дольше этого несчастного if. if - примитивная и быстрая операция. Любая арифметика, будет медленнее, а уж с плавающей точкой функции применять- вообще маразм

Comment: @MBo да тоже верно, второй вариант наверно будет самый быстрый сейчас, но я не знаю по поводу `pow` может быть он быстрее будет

Comment: Быстрые варианты - c if и с массивом.

Comment: Я скомпилировал 2рой вариант с оптимизацией, компилятор как то пропускает уловия if он кажись смог оптимизировать код без него.
Карочи вариант 2 самый быстрый.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если уж хочется максимально быстро, то скорее всего так: https://ideone.com/t5ZopF

```
int i;

START: for (i=1; ; i*=1000)
{
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  if (i == 1000000) goto START;
}
```

Comment: не уверен что goto это хороший вариант использование, так еще и в цикл, но идея прикольная.

Comment: @tomi, надо проверять, во что оно скомпилируется, но по идее переход на следующую итерацию - это уже jmp, а через goto ьмы подменяем его другим переходом. `START: mov eax, 1;
LOOP: print eax;
test eax, 1000000;
jz START;
mul eax, 1000;
jmp LOOP;`. Не думаю, что можно сделать эффективнее этого (ну кроме анролла цикла). Правда остаётся вопрос, поймёт ли компилятор, что я от него хотел такой код.

Comment: @tomi, gcc понял лишнего и сделал анролл: https://godbolt.org/z/dMsPbf: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThGl7.png.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так (я с с++ не знаком и проверить не могу, поэтому пример на другом псевдоязыке):

```
for(;;) {
    i %= 3
    print (1000**i)
    i += 1
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112246/discussion-on-answer-by----3--1-1000-1000000--).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; i<1000000;)
{
  cout<<i<<"/n";
  i*=1000;
}
```

Вот так)

Comment: И в вывод получим `1/n1000/n`.

Comment: Да, вывод не такой, который нужен ТС. Исправьте вопрос с помощью кнопки править

Comment: в вывод мы получим 1, 1000, 1000000

Comment: @Александр Нет. Вывод будет `1/n1000/n`. Проверьте сами.